# jQuery if and else statements both executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a script that will add a class to an element if the page title matches the textual value of an `<a>` tag. The else statement in my script is to cover when none of the page titles match the nav items and the active link is assigned to the `Home` menu item (i.e. the first in the nav bar).

I have a menu that's like this:

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <!-- Page title - My Cool Website -->
    <li> <a href="#">About Us</a> </li>
    <!-- Page title - About Us -->
    // etc....
</ul>
```

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var title = $(document).attr("title");
    $(".menu li a").each(function (e) {
        var a = $(this).text();
        var exists = title.match(a);
        if (exists) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        } else {
            $(".menu li a").first().addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

The if and else statements seem to be executing so both the first and the matched elements now have an `active` class added to them.

I've tried using `stopPropagation();` and `return false` at the end of my statement but to no success.

Can anyone tell me the reason why both are executing? I assume I'm not jumping through the DOM elegantly but javascript is a little rusty.

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle of the problem

Comment: That is because you have multiple `<a>s`. Some or the other `a` will satisfy `if()` or `else`

Comment: @Tushar the script is designed to work over multiple pages with a `<title>` tag so I'm unable to provide a working jsFiddle.

Comment: I guess you have to declare the `exist` variable outside of the `each` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind your issue is that you have mutiple anchor `<a>`s, some or the other will satisfy an `if()` or `else` if you add these conditions inside the loop.

The `exists` should be outside the each loop. You need to check if no elements match the `title` after the elements are traverse i.e. outside the loop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var exists = false;
    var title = $(document).attr("title");
    $(".menu li a").each(function(e) { 
        var a = $(this).text(); 
        exists = title.match(a);
        if(exists) {
            $(this).addClass("active"); 
                return false; //break if statement matches.            
        }
    });
    if(!exists){
        $(".menu li a").first().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this friend, you've helped me think about how to exit out of an if statement condition gracefully :) correct answer!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is your each loop, assume you found the match in the second a but still the each loop continues so the first element will again get the class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var title = $(document).attr("title");
    var exists;
    $(".menu li a").each(function (e) {
        var a = $(this).text();
        exists = title.match(a);
        if (exists) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!exists) {
        $(".menu li a").first().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 'exists' variable reinitialize for every item. That's the problem. Use this code instead:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var title = $(document).attr("title");
    var exists = false;
    $(".menu li a").each(function (e) {
        var a = $(this).text();

         if(title.match(a))
         {
         exists = true;
         return false;
         }
       });
    if (exists) {
      $(this).addClass("active");
     } 
     else {
      $(".menu li a").first().addClass("active");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var title = $(document).attr("title");
    $(".menu li a").each(function(e) { 
        var a = $(this).text(); 
        var exists = title.match(a);
        if(exists) {
            $(this).addClass("active");             
        } 
    });
    $(".menu li:first-child a").addClass("active")  
});
```